# Laravel redis storing data server side

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I have used laravel redis but when i trying store cache data to redis it will show in all other pcs like server side how can i make client side?

I have used redis server for my website
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let me try to explain you something:

> Redis is a server side cache system. check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redis#introduction

So if you saved data on it make sure you use proper methods to make the data available to an allowed user, you can use authentication to achieve this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a server side Cache service and mostly use for Data caching.

> Read about **Data Caching** topic for more info.